# JAGS Random Effects Model Prediction

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, glm-math, jags

I'm trying to model a bayesian regression using an index as response (D47), temperature as predictor (Temp) and considering the random effects of a discrete variable (Material). I've found really good information regarding non-hierarchical regressions, some posts including even a prediction strategy for these models. Despite this, I've found a remarkable problem when predicting D47 values in my model, mostly because of the random intercept.

Is there any way to deal with a random intercept during the prediction of a JAGS regression?

Thanks for your answer,

```
model1<-"model {
# Priors
mu_int~dnorm(0, 0.0001) # Mean hyperparameter for random intercepts
sigma_int~dunif(0, 100) # SD hyperparameter for random intercepts
tau_int <- 1/(sigma_int*sigma_int)
for (i in 1:n) {
alpha[i]~dnorm(mu_int, tau_int) # Random intercepts
}
beta~dnorm(0, 0.01) # Common slope
sigma_res~dunif(0, 100) # Residual standard deviation
tau_res <- 1/(sigma_res*sigma_res)
# Likelihood
for (i in 1:n) {
mu[i] <- alpha[Mat[i]]+beta*Temp[i] # Expectation
D47[i]~dnorm(mu[i], tau_res) # The actual (random) responses
}
}"
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the "remarkable problem" ?

Comment: The question is: Can I predict D47 values using this JAGS model? I haven't found any information regarding predictions based on random intercept models for JAGS. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can make predictions with the random intercepts, all you need to do is specify it as some sort of derived quantity.

Try adding something like this to the model.

```
for(i in 1:(n)){
D47_pred[i] <- dnorm(mu[i], tau_res)
}
```

And then track D47_pred as a parameter.

edit:

Also, you need to change how you specify the prior for the random intercept.  This will take a couple steps (updated code here from comments).

You will need to add a new constant to your data list, which represents the number of unique groups in vector Mat. I have labeled it M in this case (e.g. 4 groups in Mat, M = 4)

```
for (j in 1:(M)){ 
alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu_int, tau_int) # Random intercepts
}
```

This specification just makes the correct number of random intercepts for your model

Comment: I really appreciate your help and explanations!. That solves my questions. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @M_Fidino, I've included your suggestion on alpha prior, but I'm having an error:

`Error in jags.model(file = textConnection(model1), data = dat, inits = list(init.rng1,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 7.
Attempt to redefine node alpha[18]`, is there any other alternative to your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I think what you need to do is this instead... You will need to add a new constant to your data list, which represents the number of unique groups in vector `Mat`. I have labeled it `M` in this case (e.g. 4 groups in Mat, M = 4)

`for (j in 1:(M)){
alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu_int, tau_int)
}`

The error happened because you have repeated numbers in the `Mat` vector, and you are telling it to effectively write over itself, which it does not want to do. This specification just makes the correct number of random intercepts for your model.