# Predicting new values in jags (mixed model)

Tags: r, regression, jags

I asked a similar question a while ago on how to get model predictions in JAGS for mixed models. [Here's my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186075/jags-random-effects-model-prediction).

This time, I'm trying to get predictions for the same model but using new data and not the original that was used to fit the model.

```
model<-"model {
# Priors
mu_int~dnorm(0, 0.0001)
sigma_int~dunif(0, 100)
tau_int <- 1/(sigma_int*sigma_int)
for (j in 1:(M)){ 
alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu_int, tau_int)
}
beta~dnorm(0, 0.01)
sigma_res~dunif(0, 100)
tau_res <- 1/(sigma_res*sigma_res)
# Likelihood
for (i in 1:n) {
mu[i] <- alpha[Mat[i]]+beta*Temp[i] # Expectation
D47[i]~dnorm(mu[i], tau_res) # The actual (random) responses
}
for(i in 1:(n)){
D47_pred[i] <- dnorm(mu[i], tau_res)
}
}"
```

I know this mcan be done using the posterior distributions of the resulting parameters but I'm wondering if it could also be implemented inside jags.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely could be done inside JAGS.  If you wanted predictions for new values of `Temp` for some of the same observations in `Mat`, you would just have to append them to the existing data  with a corresponding `D47` value of `NA`.